# Assistance required with getting javascript function to run

Tags: javascript

[edit]
resolved: I moved the trigger into the ajax function immediately after the call is fired to the other script.  I was able to work that out following the addition of an 'alert' to the JS function.  so there's a tip for other relative novices: use alerts in your functions to be clearer about when they are triggered, and if they are being triggered. 
[/edit]

The following code is a calculator-like form.  The value is entered to the textbox via the calculator buttons and then the 'CASH' submit button is clicked to fire of an ajax call to another script. That script then displays the output in this same page.

All that is working fine.

However, the textbox with the value should be emptied 'onsubmit' but that part isn't working.  Please help me understand why the JS function 'clearCalc' seems not to be being triggered.

[edit]
I added an alert to the function and it is being triggered bur too soon.  onosubmit triggers it before the form is submitted.  I need to clear the textbox value after the ajax has been fired off.  How can I achive that please?

[/edit]

```
print qq(
  <div id='till_keypad'>
  <form name="vform" id="vform" onsubmit="clearCalc(vform);">
    <div>
    <label for="till_payment_input"><strong>Amount:</strong> </label>
      <input type="text" id='till_payment_input' name="till_payment_input" placeholder="Amount paid" />
    </div> 
    <div id='row1'>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="7" value="7" id="7" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='7'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="8" value="8" id="8" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='8'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="9" value="9" id="9" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='9'"/>
      <input type="button" class="rButton" name="refund" value="Refund" id="refund" />
    </div>
    <div id='row2'>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="4" value="4" id="4" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='4'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="5" value="5" id="5" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='5'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="6" value="6" id="6" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='6'"/>
      <input type="button" class="rButton" name="returns" value="Returns" id="returns" />
    </div>
    <div id='row3'>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='1'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="2" value="2" id="2" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='2'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="3" value="3" id="3" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='3'"/>
      <input type="button" class="rButton" name="credit_note" value="Credit Note" id="credit_note" />
    </div>
    <div id='row4'>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="0" value="0" id="0" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='0'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="10" value="." id="10" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='.'"/>
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="11" value="00" id="11" onClick="document.vform.till_payment_input.value+='00'"/>
      <input type="button" class="rButton" name="discount" value="Discount" id="discount" />
    </div>
    <div id='row5'>
      <input type="submit" class="cashButton" name="paid_with" value="CASH" id="paid_with" />
      <input type="submit" class="cardButton" name="paid_with2" value="CARD" id="paid_with2" />
      <input type="submit" class="voucherButton" name="paid_with3" value="VOUCHER" id="paid_with3" />
      <input type="submit" class="voucherButton" name="" value="" id="" /> 
    </div>
    <div id='row6'>
      <button type="button" class="voidButtonA" onclick="ClearFields();">CE</button>
      <button type="button" class="voidButtonA" onclick="removeChar();">C</button>
      <input type="button" class="voidButtonB" name="void" value="VOID Sale" id="void" />
      <input type="button" class="voidButtonB" name="" value="" id="" />
    </div>
    <div id='row7'>
      <input type="submit" class="oButton" name="back_office" value="Back Office" id="back_office" />
      <input type="submit" class="oButton" name="x_reading" value="X Reading" id="x_reading" />
      <input type="submit" class="oButton" name="y_reading" value="Y Reading" id="y_reading" />
      <input type="submit" class="oButton" name="" value="" id="" /> 
    </div>


    <div class='clear'> </div>);





print qq(
  </form>
</div>
<div class='clear'></div>);





print qq(
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function clearCalc(vform) {
  // vform.till_payment_input.value == "";
return  document.getElementById("till_payment_input").value = "";
} 
</script>);
```

Comment: I don't know why you think it is not being triggered. I setup [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdpbkL24/) to test your code and it seems to work. The only problem I had was that all the submits navigates to another page which you can prevent by uncommenting the `preventDefault` line. For me the input field is cleared in any case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I discovered that my AJAX function was (sort of), complicating it.  I moved the trigger for the clear_calc function into the AJAX code and it is now being triggered at the correct time.